# Intersection of 2 arrays using sets

Tags: java, arrays, set

My requirement is the if i have 2 strings, i should get the intersection of 2 strings-means returning the common elements of the strings without duplicacy.

My approach was:

```
String str1="Character";
String str2="National";

Set<Character> set1=new HashSet<Character>();
Set<Character> set2=new HashSet<Character>();

for(char c:str1.toLowerCase().toCharArray()){
    set1.add(c);
}

for(char c:str2.toLowerCase().toCharArray()){
    set2.add(c);
}

Set<Character> inter=new HashSet<Character>(set1);
Set<Character> union=new HashSet<Character>(set1);

inter.retainAll(set2);
union.addAll(set2);
```

Now the intersection contains the intersection and union contains the union as:

Intersection of sets:[t, a]
Union of sets:[t, e, c, r, a, n, o, l, h, i]

But i want is to convert these sets back to strings as "ta" and"tecranolhi" .

I am using `String arr1[]=inter.toArray(new String[0]);` but it gives an error.

```
**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException: java.lang.Character
        at java.util.AbstractCollection.toArray(Unknown Source)
        at StringInter.main(StringInter.java:22)**
```

Can someone clarify this?

Comment: `inter` is a `Set` of `Character`, not `String`. Why don't you use a `Character` array instead?

Comment: What approach to be followed to convert these characters in set to a string?

Comment: Create a `StringBuilder`, iterate through the `Set` and append each character. Finally, call `sb.toString()` and assign back this result to your `String` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (Character c : inter) {
    builder.append(c.charValue());
}
String interAsString = builder.toString();
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution.It works out for me. Can you pls tell me what is the time complexity of retainAll() and addAll() methods. Or say, methods of HashSet in general?

Answer (score 3):

As I said, create a `StringBuilder`, iterate through the `Set` and append each character. Finally, call `sb.toString()` and assign back this result to your `String` variable.

Here's also a [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) solution :

```
String s = inter.stream().collect(StringBuilder::new, 
                                  StringBuilder::append,
                                  StringBuilder::append).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the code snippet below:

```
StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
Iterator i = inter.iterator();
while(i.hasNext())
{
  b.append(i.next().toString());
}
String interString = b.toString();
```

Now, interString will have what you want. Hope this helps.